# How to use regex in android

Tags: android, regex

I need help to match a string with a regex. An example of the string is

```
"Longitude: 34.847368\nLatitude: 30.435345\nAltitiude: 130.34554"
```

So in this string, the numbers can change, and its possible there is no decimal value.

When I try this code,

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("Longitude: -?\\d+(\\.\\d+)?\nLatitude: -?\\d+(\\.\\d+)?\nAltitude: -?\\d+(\\.\\d+)?");
```

I get an error saying `\.` is an invalid escape sequence, can any one help?

Comment: Going out on a limb here, but have you tried removing the slashes before the dots?

Comment: but if I do, the dot can represent anything, but it needs to represent a real dot, so i thought it needs to be escaped...

Comment: @DarshanComputing: Removing would work, but it is better to keep it there. The problem with the whole thing is that, backslash must be escaped with another backslash in Java String.

Comment: Oh, I see.  Escape your slash to get a slash in the string.  ("\\.")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use a double slash, otherwise Java sees it as a String escape sequence, not a Regex escape sequence. Try this:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("Longitude: \\d+(\\.\\d+)?\nLatitude: \\d+(\\.\\d+)?\nAltitude: \\d+(\\.\\d+)?");
```

Comment: for some reason my regex isnt getting a match, see first post, can anyone tell me whats wrong? But putting double slashes made it compile, so thanks.

Comment: In your example input line you've spelled "Altitude" wrong (you have it spelled as "Altit*i*ude").  Maybe that's why?

Answer (score 0):

Soxxeh and aroth are almost definitly right, but in future, maybe this will help:

http://gskinner.com/RegExr/

I use it all the time :D